# Can a Parallel.For be descendant?

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library

Could a Parallel.For be written for a regressive loop?

Not considering the usage of a variable to provide (N - index), could I write a parallel.for to do this?

```
 For X as integer = 2000 to 0 step -1
  ...
 Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a method is not provided by the `Parallel` class.

In addition, you should not rely on iterations of your code to be run in ***any particular order*** when using `Parallel.For`. There is no guarantee that it will be run from lowest to highest, or vice verse.

Comment: Thanks Glorin. You helped me to understand it better.